# select rows satisfying some criteria and with maximum value in a certain column

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table of metadata for updates to a software package. The table has columns `id, name, version`. I want to select all rows where the name is one of some given list of names and the version is maximum of all the rows with that name.

For example, given these records:

```
+----+------+---------+
| id | name | version |
+----+------+---------+
| 1  | foo  | 1       |
| 2  | foo  | 2       |
| 3  | bar  | 4       |
| 4  | bar  | 5       |
+----+------+---------+
```

And a task "give me the highest versions of records "foo" and "bar", I want the result to be:

```
+----+------+---------+
| id | name | version |
+----+------+---------+
| 2  | foo  | 2       |
| 4  | bar  | 5       |
+----+------+---------+
```

What I come up with so far, is using nested queries:

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM updates 
  WHERE (
    id IN (SELECT id 
             FROM updates 
             WHERE name = 'foo' 
             ORDER BY version DESC 
             LIMIT 1)
  ) OR (
    id IN (SELECT id 
             FROM updates 
             WHERE name = 'bar' 
             ORDER BY version DESC 
             LIMIT 1)
  );
```

This works, but feels wrong. If I want to filter on more names, I have to replicate the whole subquery multiple times. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: My go-to answer for the case (as has been clarified): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/sql-select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select distinct on (name) id, name, version
from metadata
where name in ('foo', 'bar')
order by name, version desc
```

Comment: I am a big fan of `DISTINCT ON`, but it's not the right tool when looking for `all rows` - which can include duplicate names. More importantly: this retrieves one row (with with the maximum version) for *every* `name` passing the `WHERE` clause, which is subtly different from what the question asks for, AIUI.

Comment: This seems to do what I want and looks the simplest of all the answers so far, so I'm accepting it. Thanks!

Comment: @adam: Upon re-reading I see that I seem to have misunderstood your question.

Comment: @erwin: could be that I haven't phrased my question correctly. I want, for each name, the row with the maximum version of all the rows with that name. For each name, I want only one row. Doesn't this answer do that?

Comment: To the OP: What if there are *two* (or more)  records for a name, each with the *same* maximal value for version? (this is the *ties* issue in my discussion with Erwin)

Comment: For one, I missed `with that name` in `the version is maximum of all the rows with that name`. This was just a misunderstanding on my side. The other issue is with *ties*, like @wildplasser just pointed out. It is not clear from the question that `(name, version)` would be defined unique. In this case you would need to clarify how to break ties or retrieve all qualifying peers with a method like I have in my updated answer.

Comment: In my case, `(name, version)` is always unique. I should have put this into the original question.

Comment: @adam: Like 9 out of 10 people forget about that.

Answer (score 3):

`NOT EXISTS` is a way to avoid unwanted *sub optimal* tuples:

```
SELECT * 
FROM updates uu
WHERE uu.zname IN ('foo', 'bar')
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM updates nx
    WHERE nx.zname = uu.zanme
    AND nx.version > uu.version
    );
```

Note: I replaced `name` by `zname`, since it is *more or less* a keyword in postgresql.

Comment: `name` is [*not* a reserved word at all](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html), but it's still bad practice to use it as identifier, because its not descriptive.

Comment: I thought it was used as a typename for table and column names in older versions. But maybe I just like to prefix everything with a `z`...

Comment: Also, and more importantly, I think the query is *incorrect* in the same way @Clodoaldo's query is. It gets maximum versions *per name* instead of rows with the *maximum of all rows*.

Comment: The example (desired output) in the OQ does suggest that the OP wants the maximal version *per name*. Not sure, though (the OQ does has the `WHERE (subquery) OR (subquery)` , though) (s)he does not mention what to do in the case of ties.

Comment: You are right. I seem to have misread the question. There is only the matter of ties that is overlooked so often.

Comment: Yeah, that's why you picked rank() instead of row_number(). I hesitated too, to add a tie breaker (would imply an ugly OR in the subquery condition ...)

Comment: Actrually, your query includes all peers and is subtly different from @Clodoaldo's version in that. Technically, yours (or mine) is correct. Although the OP may want @Clodoaldo's version without having said so in the Q. Most likely `(name, version)` is unique or should be to begin with.

Comment: Yes, SQL is easy: *once you master the syntax, everything becomes a data modelling issue*

Answer (score 2):

Update after rereading the Q:

> I want to select **all rows** where the name is one of some given list
>   of names and the version is maximum of all the rows **with that name**.

If there can be ties (multiple rows with the maximum version per `name`), you could use the window function [`rank()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) in a subquery. Requires PostgreSQL 8.4+.

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT *, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY version DESC) AS rnk
   FROM   updates 
   WHERE  name IN ('foo', 'bar')
   )
WHERE rnk = 1;
```